# Data from a JSON API combined with local database in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I would like to combine data retrieved from an API with local database data in a new JSON. But I think I'm doing this wrong. Here is my code :

```
@data = ActiveSupport::JSON.decode(@api_data)
@data.each do |key|
  if key['state'] == "active"
    user_id = key['id']
    user_database = User.where(:user_id => user_id).take
    @userlist = []
    unless user_database.blank?
      user_data = {
        :user_id => key['id'],
        :enrolement_start_date => key['start_at'],
        :enrolement_end_date => key['end_at'],
        :user_interest => user_database.interests,
        :user_discipline_id => user_database.discipline_id,
      }
      @userlist.push(user_data)
    end
  end
end
@userlist = @userlist.to_json
```

Actually, it's working but I only receive the last user as result. I don't figure how to make it works :-/ Many thanks in advance !

Comment: Where is `@courselist` defined, is it supposed to be there?

Comment: Corrected, It's a simple example from a more longer one ;) Sorry

Comment: You should be getting an error where you're calling `take` because `take` requires one parameter.  Check the value of `user_database` after that call.

Comment: Also these lines should probably be like: `:user_id => key['id'],` and the other two lines after it, notice the rocket notation.

Comment: You right, It's like that in my code, I'll edit it, sorry it's late here :) The `user_database` returns me an object `#<User:0x000000037e1820>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@userlist = []
```

that line, each time through the loop

```
@data.each do |key|
```

is clearing out the previous data by re-initializing @userlist.  Then you're returning the user you added last, since all the others were thrown away the last time you assigned an empty array to @userlist.

Just move

```
@userlist = []
```

above

```
@data.each do |key|
```

and you should be good.